# Timeout connecting to particular server from Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, https, xamarin, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Xamarin iOS app that hits a timeout (10 minutes) when connecting to a number of our internal https servers. The code that the app uses to connect is:

```
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

[Headers and content are added to message here - I can't easily post up
the details for security reasons, but if anyone thinks that that might
be causing the problem, I'll work something out.]

System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler();
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 900000000;
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

The message I receive on timeout is: `A task was cancelled`.

I've looked into this quite a bit and these are my findings:

1. This code is also used in a Windows app which connects to the server fine.
2. I have connected to this server just fine from a native iOS app.
3. **When I try to connect through Fiddler with it set to decrypt HTTPS traffic, it works fine.**
4. I have turned off App Transport Security by adding this to the app's Info.plist:

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
   </dict>
   ```
5. I have run the ATS diagnostics tool (`/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics [URL]`) from the same machine as the iOS simulator and everything passes.
6. <s>I updated to the alpha track of Xamarin to get the [Xamarin.iOS 9.8 HTTP changes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/#NSUrlSessionHandler) but still got the timeout.</s> (see comment below)
7. I am able to connect to other internal servers from the app. I ran tests using [SSL labs' tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) on a broken server and two working servers and found that the broken server did not support TLS 1.1 and RC4 whereas the working servers did. I then tried switching both of these off on one of the working servers in an attempt to break it, but I could still connect.

Anyone any ideas what else could be the problem and what else I could try?! I've highlighted the point about Fiddler above as I suspect it could be a big clue - how does the server look different to the app when it connects through Fiddler in decrypt mode?

Comment: In terms of Fiddler; Fiddler is actually connecting to your server using the **man-in-the-middle** approach and the app is connecting to Fiddler (which generates a SSL cert for your app to negotiate). In terms of iOS Transport  Security, TLS protocol version 1.2 is required (unless ATS is turned off). Forward secrecy is also a requirement, along with a supported cipher suited RSA 2048+ bit key, etc, etc.. ASSUMING you added the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to the correct plist and you can NOT connect, it is NOT an ATS issue. Apple docs actually says, "look elsewhere" :-/

Comment: If ATS is not the root issue, I would set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true and not use SSL as a starting point with that server. Use just HTTP, can you connect? After that, Wiresharking using a transparent proxy is the way to watch what is working from the known good servers vs the "bad" server.

Comment: I am as sure as I can be that I've used the correct plist, and also I guess the `nscurl` check would have highlighted any issues there. As for HTTP, the server has a gateway which is set to convert HTTP requests into HTTPS. I might be able to turn off the rule temporarily but it'll have to wait till Monday now. I'll let you know the result!

Comment: Any calls to System.Net.Http bypasses ATS so it doesn't matter what your ATS settings are. Since your code works fine in a Windows App I suspect the same call is getting killed from the iOS side. I believe I ran into the same issues before uploading large audio files and it worked around it by switching to NSUrlSession. Since you're posting files to the server it's probably best if you switch to NSUrlSession using a background configuration. This will allow your upload to continue uploading in the background even if the user sends your app to the background.

Comment: I don't really have an answer for this issue, but the workaround was to [switch from using the default Mono TLS provider to Apple's native provider](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/#Apple_TLS_support) in the latest Xamarin alpha. (I thought I'd already done this originally by just updating Xamarin but I'd missed an additional step).

I'd still be interested in why the Mono TLS provider was having issues on iOS, but seeing as the Apple provider looks set to become the new default anyway, it doesn't seem worth looking into it any further at this stage.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I never got a chance to change the gateway settings, but thanks for the suggestion anyway.